# How do I pay the Tunnel Man?

Tags: spelunky

In the PC version of Spelunky, I don't know what buttons to press to pay the Tunnel Man. How can I pay him?

Comment: Hi @Leadri, if your question can't be submitted due to quality standards, please do not pad your answer out with spam. Instead, consider adding more detail to your question, as the more detail we have about your problem, the better we can help you.

Comment: Thanks but there's no more detail. Question is simple. What can I do? Also it's not "how much". I know how much I should pay but I cannot pay.

Comment: @Leadri That, right there, is more detail.  The reason there's a minimum character limit is to encourage providing more information.  Now that you have more detail, why don't you edit your question to include that information?

Comment: @fbueckert It's not a detail. My question is changed by FAE and I'm telling it's not my question. It's irrelevant.

Comment: @Leadri I think the question edit to change "how do I?" to "how much do I?" was just an honest mistake as they tried to remove all that extra text in the original question. Is this new edit better?

Answer (score 2):

Press up and down to change the amount of money you're offering him, then press your default 'use' key to pay him. The tunnel to Area 2 costs $100,000, the tunnel to Area 3 costs $200,000, and the tunnel to Area 4 costs $300,000

From the [PC wiki](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Tunnel_Man).

Comment: I tried this but where can I see amount of money? Nothing changes when I press up and down.

Comment: There should be yellow text with `DONATE: ` before the amount at the bottom of the screen. Can you add a screenshot with what you see?

Comment: It seems it was a bug in v1.1. There is a v1.2 community update that fixes many problems including this problem. Here is link: http://mossmouth.com/forums/index.php?topic=1257.0